# Does PostgreSQL have a variable character storage layer that optimizes storage space by automatic dedupe?

Tags: postgresql, varchar, duplication, string

My application has a Product and a Purchased table.

The Purchased table includes a full copy of the Product row at time of purchase, so that, even if a product name or description was changed, the purchase table maintains a historical record of the product details.

Purchased.name and Purchased.description fields are taking up too much space. On average, 1 of 30 strings in these fields are unique, and 29 of 30 are duplicates.

I would like to avoid creating a HistoricalProduct table, as many facets of Product change on a regular basis, and that table would grow quite large, too.

Is there a way to get PostgreSQL to manage deduplication of these variable character fields automatically for me?

Comment: There is no mechanism that will do this for you behind the scenes.  However, you can normalize these data into two separate tables (`purchased_name` and `purchased_description`, for example) and have a foreign key in the original table referencing these two.

Comment: How long are those strings? Postgres compresses values automatically that exceed a certain length

Comment: Name is 88 bits on average. Description is 350 bits.

Comment: You mean bytes?

Comment: I meant bits. Name is 11 bytes, description is 44 bytes.

Answer (score -1):

PostgreSQL has functions for regular expressions. 
[PostgreSQL string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html) 
So you can write triggers (function + dml event) to be done what you need. I don't believe it has some optimizer that compress strings across the records. Or maybe I didn't understand what you mean in the question.